# Why would a range delete request timeout/abort?

Tags: excel, office-scripts

This is an office script in Excel which selects table rows with a specific condition, moves them to a different table, and then deletes the affected table rows from the original table.

The script had been working as expected, but now it only deletes 1 row (the bottom row, there should be additional rows deleted) and then stops functioning at the delete function and generates the following error:

Line 88: Range delete: The request is aborted.

Line 88 is the final line below, starting with "sheet.getRange...."

Edit: It should be noted that when I run this script in Desktop, no errors are generated and it functions as expected. The error appears to be limited to browser instances.

```
const rowAddressToRemove = rangeView.getRows().map((r) => r.getRange().getAddress());
rowAddressToRemove.splice(0,1);


  // Display number of rows being added to Posted table
  console.log(`Adding ${rowAddressToRemove.length} rows to Posted Recoveries table.`);

  // Clear all the criteria currently applied to the autoFilter.
  sourceTable.getAutoFilter().clearCriteria();

  // Important: Remove the rows starting at the bottom of the table.
  // Otherwise, the lower rows change position before they are deleted.
  console.log(
    `Removing ${rowAddressToRemove.length} rows from the Pending Recoveries table.`
  );
  console.log(rowAddressToRemove);
  const sheet = sourceTable.getWorksheet();
  rowAddressToRemove.reverse().forEach((address) => {
    sheet.getRange(address).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
  });
```

It appears to timeout before generating the error. I tried moving the "clear filter" code further down, thinking maybe the clearing of filters was creating the problem, but that created a whole other problem, so I don't think that's it.

I am expecting the code to delete the same table rows that were copied and inserted elsewhere. Instead, after the table rows are inserted, only one table row is being deleted, rather than all of them.

I updated the script to output the rowAddressToRemove to the console and the output includes the exact ranges, I expected. "Pending" is the name of the worksheet. Those ranges are the table rows in question that should be deleted. Example console output:

(2) ["Pending!A9:G9", "Pending!A10:G10"]
0: "Pending!A9:G9"
1: "Pending!A10:G10"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `rowAddressToRemove` variable contain? If you logged it to the console, does it contain what you'd expect?

Comment: Good question. I logged it to the console and it does contain the ranges I'd expect.

Comment: Okay great. Would you mind updating your post with the data so it can be reviewed / tested by others?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run a modified version of your code without error:

```js
    function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    
      let rowAddressToRemove = ["Pending!A9:G9", "Pending!A10:G10"]
      let sourceTable = workbook.getTable("Table1")
    
      const sheet = sourceTable.getWorksheet();
      rowAddressToRemove.reverse().forEach((address) => {
        sheet.getRange(address).delete(ExcelScript.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
      });
    }
```

In terms of where you may be getting your errors, I would look into your sourceTable. If the table doesn't exist, it won't be able to get the sheet name. And code after that that expects it to have a sheet name will fail. If you wrote code like:

```js
      console.log(`SourceTable name: ${sourceTable.getName()}`)
    
      console.log(`Sheet name is ${sheet.getName()}`)
```

Does it work?

Comment: It does work. The console outputs the source table name and the sheet name correctly. It is worth noting again that the script functions without errors in Desktop, but generates errors in browsers/online Excel instances. It typically deletes one or two rows and then aborts with an error before completing the script.